# Split with single colon but not double colon using regex

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string like this

```
"yJdz:jkj8h:jkhd::hjkjh"
```

I want to split it using colon as a separator, but not a double colon. Desired result:

```
("yJdz", "jkj8h", "jkhd::hjkjh")
```

I'm trying with:

```
re.split(":{1}", "yJdz:jkj8h:jkhd::hjkjh")
```

but I got a wrong result.

In the meanwhile I'm escaping `"::"`, with `string.replace("::", "$$")`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could split on `(?<!:):(?!:)`. This uses two [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (a lookbehind and a lookahead) which assert that a valid match only has one colon, without a colon before or after it.

To explain the pattern:

```
(?<!:)  # assert that the previous character is not a colon
:       # match a literal : character
(?!:)   # assert that the next character is not a colon
```

Both lookarounds are needed, because if there was only the lookbehind, then the regular expression engine would match the first colon in `::` (because the previous character isn't a colon), and if there was only the lookahead, the second colon would match (because the next character isn't a colon).

Comment: How can you do this with POSIX RE (no lookaround)?

Answer (score 14):

You can do this with [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), if you want:

```
>>> s = "yJdz:jkj8h:jkhd::hjkjh"
>>> l = re.split("(?<!:):(?!:)", s)
>>> print l
['yJdz', 'jkj8h', 'jkhd::hjkjh']
```

This regex essentially says "match a `:` that is not followed by a `:` or preceded by a `:`"