# Splitting on comma either outside quotes when escaped quotes exist, or outside brackets

Tags: java, string, split

Is it possible to split a String with the conditions as below?

> - split by , (i.e. comma)
> - on each element, ignore checking comma within the first ' and the last '
> - on each element, ignore checking comma within the first ( and the last )

e.g.

```
String source = "to_char(DATE, 'YYYY,MM,DD'), 'I am sad :(', to_char(DATE, ('YYYY(MM,DD)')), to_char(DATE, ('YYYY,MM,DD)')), to_char(DATE, ('YYYY(MM,DD')), NAME, to_char(DATE, '(YYYY)MM,DD'), CITY || ', (UK)', CITY || ', US''s CITY', CITY || ', UK'";

String[] expected = new String[]{
"to_char(DATE, 'YYYY,MM,DD')", 
"'I am sad :('",
"to_char(DATE, ('YYYY(MM,DD)'))", // brackets within quotes within brackets
"to_char(DATE, ('YYYY,MM,DD)'))", // missing open bracket in quotes
"to_char(DATE, ('YYYY(MM,DD'))", // missing close bracket in quotes
"NAME", 
"to_char(DATE, '(YYYY)MM,DD')", 
"CITY || ', (UK)'", 
"CITY || ', US''s CITY'", // escape a single quote in quotes
"CITY || ', UK'"
};

String[] result = splitElements(source);
assert expected.equals(result);
```

The first 2 bullet points can be achieved by [Splitting on comma outside quotes when escaped quotes exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402929/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes-when-escaped-quotes-exist/32403228#32403228)

This would be really useful when manipulating with SQL. E.g. split the items, append, insert, prepend items etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind giving another example of the 2nd and 3rd bullet points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it is kind of long but fairly straight-forward, just keep track of how many parens and inside or outside quotes.

```
String[] splitElements(String source) {
    int parencount = 0;
    boolean q = false;
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        char c = source.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
            case ',':
                if (!q && parencount == 0) {
                    l.add(sb.toString());
                    sb.setLength(0);
                } else {
                    sb.append(c);
                }
                break;

            case '(':
                if(!q) parencount++;
                sb.append(c);
                break;

            case ')':
                if(!q) parencount--;
                sb.append(c);
                break;

            case '\'':
                q = ! q;
                sb.append(c);
                break;

            default:
                sb.append(c);
                break;
        }
    }
    String last = sb.toString();
    l.add(last);
    String sa[] = l.toArray(new String[l.size()]);
    return sa;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `sb = new StringBuilder()` to reset the builder, just call `sb.setLength(0)`.

Comment: This is going to have a problem, at least as far as proper SQL syntax is concerned, if you have closing parenthesis inside quotes.

Comment: @WillShackleford Thanks for the reply. The problem is, there could be any number of ( within '', some of which may not have matching close brackets.

Comment: A string literal with unbalanced parenthesis characters will throw off logic. Add `if (!q)` round `parencount++` and `parencount--`.

Comment: @WillShackleford I'll edit the input if you don't mind to cover the un-matching brackets problem.

Comment: put in @Andreas suggestion ( I think)

Comment: Now you are good. Final comment: No need to copy to array at the beginning. Just use `char c = source.charAt(i)`. Also: Define `l`.

Comment: I thought I had them. At any rate they should be back now.

Comment: @WillShackleford I have removed my comment about missing q and parencount after a refresh. Would you mind making the logic in a method like splitElements() with return type String[] or an array to make the solution more complete? Thanks a lot

Comment: @WillShackleford I have run couple of tests. It seems to always miss the last item in the array list.

Comment: @WillShackleford e.g. The result doesn't contain the last "CITY || ', UK'"

Comment: @WillShackleford I added l.add(sb.toString()); before String sa[] = l.toArray(new String[l.size()]); It now works for all of my tests. Would you mind adding this line? Thanks

Comment: @Ming, yep I need to add that last string. Sorry about the delay in reading your message I had to run out for something.

Comment: @WillShackleford Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can done this by using [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method of java class `String` together with this

**Regex:**

```
(?<!\([^\(\)']{0,100}),(?![^\(\)']*\))(?=(?:'[^']*'|[^'])*$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\([^\(\)']{0,100}),(?![^\(\)']*\))
```

Any `,` which are not surrounded by `(...)`, note that generally negative lookbehind is required a finite quantifier here I arbitrary use `{0,100}`.

```
(?=(?:'[^']*'|[^'])*$)
```

Use lookahead to guarantee that either there is even number of `'` which count from `,` till the end of the string (regex: `(?:'[^']*')*$`) or there is string which composed of any characters except `'` till the end of the string (regex: `[^']*$`).

**Strategy:**

1. Using negative lookahead, negative lookbehind to guarantee that `,` is out of `(...)`,
2. Using lookahead to guarantee that there are only pair of `'`s ahead which count from `,` till the end of the string.

**Code Example:**

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String source = "to_char(DATE, 'YYYY,MM,DD'), to_char(DATE, ('YYYY(MM,DD)')), " +
                        "to_char(DATE, ('YYYY,MM,DD)')), to_char(DATE, ('YYYY(MM,DD')), " +
                        "NAME, to_char(DATE, '(YYYY)MM,DD'), CITY || ', (UK)', " +
                        "CITY || ', US''s CITY', CITY || ', UK', " +
                        "'I am sad :(', to_char(DATE, 'YYYY,MM,DD')";

        String delimiters = "(?<!\\([^\\(\\)']{0,100}),(?![^\\(\\)']*\\))(?=(?:'[^']*'|[^'])*$)";

        String[] tokens = source.split(delimiters);

        for(String token : tokens) {
            System.out.println(token.trim());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
to_char(DATE, 'YYYY,MM,DD')
to_char(DATE, ('YYYY(MM,DD)'))
to_char(DATE, ('YYYY,MM,DD)'))
to_char(DATE, ('YYYY(MM,DD'))
NAME
to_char(DATE, '(YYYY)MM,DD')
CITY || ', (UK)'
CITY || ', US''s CITY'
CITY || ', UK'
'I am sad :('
to_char(DATE, 'YYYY,MM,DD')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer also works for all the test cases I have. I have to say this is really clever. Thanks for also make the explanation so clear as well.

Comment: Just notice this doesn't solve splitting "'I am sad :(', to_char(DATE, 'YYYY,MM,DD')", would you mind taking a look to see if we can enhance the solution? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works really well. I also updated the original post with this scenario.

Comment: Yes it still does. I thought it didn't but I was wrong. Cheers

Comment: @Ming In case if it doesn't work please ask him to update the answer So, later this post can help other people.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested both of your solutions. I tried to accept both of your solutions but Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do so :(