# split a string without adjacent characters that matched regex in java

Tags: java, regex, split

i am first to this site.
I want to split a string without the characters that matched in regex of string split method in java.

**The string for splitting is (for eg.) :** `"conditional&&operator and ampersand&Symbol."`
**My regex-expression for spit is :** `"[^\\&]\\&[^\\&]"`
**My expectation is :** `[conditional&&operator and ampersand, Symbol]`
**But, the output is :** `[conditional&&operator and *ampersan, ymbol*]`

The code i used is:

```
String s = "conditional&&operator and ampersand&Symbol.";     
String[] sarr = s.split("[^\\&]\\&[^\\&]");     
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sarr));
```

So, please tell me what **regex** i should use to get the expected output, that is without the additional characters removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735841/split-with-single-colon-but-not-double-colon-using-regex).

What you need is a [negative look-behind](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-9-regular/9781787288706/b1eb3897-2c07-41d9-9567-5395d2729868.xhtml). In your case, you could use something like:

```java
String s = "conditional&&operator and ampersand&Symbol.";
String[] sarr = s.split("(?<!&)&(?!&)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sarr));
// output: [conditional&&operator and ampersand, Symbol.]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it's impossible to split your string by regex as you wish.
The problem is that `[^\\&]\\&[^\\&]` matches 3 characters -> `d&S` and it splits by 3 characters, so you have them removed.
You can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to split a string in this way:

```
    String s = "conditional&&operator and ampersand&Symbol.";
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^&]&[^&]").matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        final int indexOfMatchStart = matcher.start();
        final String firstPart = s.substring(0, indexOfMatchStart + 1); // + 1 to include first symbol of RegEx
        final String secondPart = s.substring(indexOfMatchStart + 2); // + 2  to skip &
        System.out.println(firstPart + secondPart); // will print conditional&&operator and ampersandSymbol.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Long code but Basic logic.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class B {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final String x = "conditional&&operator and ampersand&Symbol.";

        final String mydata = x;
        String delimString = "";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\&]\\&[^\\&]");
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        while (m.find()){
            delimString = m.group(0);
        }


    final String[] result = x.split(delimString); // Split using 'd&S'
    final String[] conResult = delimString.split("&"); //Split d&S in d and s
    System.out.println(result[0]+""+conResult[0]); // append d at the end of string
    System.out.println(conResult[1]+""+result[1]); // append s at the start of string

    }
}
```